# When using ArrayList<int[][]> how to see if an element is already in the list?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Using the `public boolean contains(Object o)` in the ArrayList library does not work in this case. Consider

```
ArrayList<int[][]> test = new ArrayList<>();

int[][] one = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
};
int[][] two = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
};
int[][] three = {
    {9,7,5},
    {1,2,4},
    {5,6,7}
};

test.add(one);
System.out.println(test.contains(one));
System.out.println(test.contains(two));
System.out.println(test.contains(three));
```

The above code returns

```
true
false
false
```

Is there a way to check for equality between the two and make sure that no duplicate values enter the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach I know is to extract it into a method using [`Arrays.deepEquals(Object[], Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29), something like -

```
public static boolean contains(List<int[][]> al, int[][] toFind) {
    for (int[][] arr : al) {
        if (Arrays.deepEquals(arr, toFind)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can test it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<int[][]> test = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
    int[][] one = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    int[][] two = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    int[][] three = { { 9, 7, 5 }, { 1, 2, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7 } };
    test.add(one);
    if (contains(test, two)) {
        System.out.println("Found two");
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Found two
```

Comment: +1, I'd prefer such a neat utility method over the effort of writing a wrapper class.

Comment: Solved my problem with ease, and is a clean solution. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to wrap the arrays in a class that provides an appropriate `equals` implementation.

```
class SquareArray {
    private int[][] array;

    public SquareArray(int[][] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int[][] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof SquareArray) && 
               Arrays.deepEquals(array, ((SquareArray)o).array);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(array);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(array);
    }
}
```

Now you would use a `List<SquareArray>`; for instance:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int[][] b = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
int[][] c = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};

SquareArray x = new SquareArray(a);
SquareArray y = new SquareArray(b);
SquareArray z = new SquareArray(c);

List<SquareArray> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(x);
System.out.println(list.contains(x));
System.out.println(list.contains(y));
System.out.println(list.contains(z));
```

```
true
false
true
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]))
- [`Arrays.deepHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode(java.lang.Object[]))
- [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose another solution using Java 8 streams and predicates:

The [`Stream#anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method may be used to check whether the given list contains a certain element. The required predicate can be build concisely using [`Arrays#deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericContainsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
        int[][] one =
        { { 1, 2, 3 },
          { 4, 5, 6 } };
        int[][] two =
        { { 1, 2, 3 },
          { 4, 5, 6 } };
        list.add(one);
        if (list.stream().anyMatch(e->Arrays.deepEquals(e, two)))
        {
            System.out.println("Found two");
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, you mentioned that your intention is to...

> ... make sure that no duplicate values enter the list

In this case, you should at least consider to not use a `List`, but a `Set` - particularly, a `Set<SquareArray>` using the `SquareArray` class that [arashajii proposed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388724/3182664).

Answer (score 0):

[`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method use the method [`equals(e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and when you use equals on array it's the same thing as using `==` hence you check for reference equality, not content.
To check if two arrays are equals you have to use [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29)`(array1, array2)` or [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29)`(nestedArray1, nestedArray2)` for nested arrays.